# Onclick inside form element

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

While fiddling something with the HTML code, I came up with a mind-boggling thing. Have a look at the code:-

```
<form class="index-form" name="LoginForm">
   <div class="index-input">
      <button onclick="myFunction();">Login</button>
   </div>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction(){
  window.location = "https://blahblah.com/auth/?client_id=fdsgsnlr";
};
</script>
```

This just added a '?' in my URL and did nothing. But when I relieve the button element from the parent form element, it works perfectly fine. I know what I did is just nonsense but still, any idea how and why it's happening?

Comment: Return false from your onclick handler - onclick="myFunction(); return false;"

Comment: Also see my edits to @VikasSachdeva answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your button is written inside `<form>` then after calling `onclick` event handler on button, your form gets submitted. Since there is no `action` attribute defined in your `<form>` element so the default is make `GET` request to the current page with any given named inputs in the form, since you have none, you just get '?'.

Now, if you return false from `onclick` event handler, then form does not get submitted and your window.location code works.

Update code should be  -

```
    <form class="index-form" name="LoginForm">
       <div class="index-input">
         <button onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Login</button>
       </div>
   </form>
   <script>
      function myFunction(){
        window.location = "https://blahblah.com/auth/?client_id=fdsgsnlr";
      };
   </script>
```

In addition

`<button>` defaults to `<button type="submit">` which submits the parent form, you can instead use `<button type="button">` which does not submit the form.

Comment: But how is this connected to the fact that I am submitting the form? Is button element has it in by default?

Comment: As @Victory clarified that <button> is by default of submit type. Clicking on any button of submit type will submit the parent form. It is basic fundamental

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form class="index-form" name="LoginForm">
   <div class="index-input">
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Login</button>
   </div>
</form>

<script>
  function myFunction(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     window.location = "https://blahblah.com/auth/?client_id=fdsgsnlr";
  };
</script>
```